# Integrat Ecwid shopping cart with my android application

Tags: android

My client want to integrate his Ecwid acoount with android application...
i get products information from Ecwid using diffrent available apis,also able to place order but cant able on further procedure for payment...
some one please help me

Comment: And you show absolutely no code at all?

Comment: i dont know which url use to pass parameters for payment.Ecwid not provide any API for built custom payment module..

Answer (score 0):

Ecwid provides Custom Payments API that should be the proper solution in your case. The documentation is here: http://kb.ecwid.com/w/page/49187841/AuthorizeNet%20Emulation#Custompaymentgateways

Hope that helps.